# How to find out the list of published component from the publication

Tags: tridion

Is there any way to find out the list of those component which has been published?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the standard search functionality for this.

On the advanced search you can select the publication/folder where you want to check

Select "Type": Component
Select "Publish Status": Published

Comment: I am unable to find the advance search option?

Answer (score 4):

You can refer below screen shot for same
[image]